# Can I select all XML attributes in SQL without knowing the attributes name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Say I have a column containing an XML string that looks something like:

```
<column type="someValue" action="anotherValue" />
```

Is there a way I can extract data from this column XML to where the results will look something like:

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| type | someValue |
| action | anothervalue |

I've Googled around for the better part of an hour now with no luck. The other solutions I've come across seem to all assume the user know the attribute name beforehand. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @x xml = N'
<column type="someValue" action="anotherValue" />
<column typeX="someValueX" actionY="anotherValueX" att3="X123"/>
<column typeY="someValueY" actionY="anotherValueY" att3="Y123"/>
';

select 
    n.a.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)') as attributename,
    n.a.value('data(.)', 'nvarchar(100)') as attributevalue
from @x.nodes('//@*') as n(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your your XMLCol is a string and not XML.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (id int,XMLCol varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'<column type="someValue" action="anotherValue" />')


Select A.ID
      ,C.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ( try_convert(xml,XMLCol) ))B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select [Key]  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
                 From  XMLData.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Key     Value
1   type    someValue
1   action  anotherValue
```

**IF your Column is XML**

```
Declare @YourTable table (id int,XMLCol xml)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'<column type="someValue" action="anotherValue" />')


Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select [Key]  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
                 From  XMLCol.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
             ) B
```